# Neo4j cypher for all node children

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Assume I have this model in neo4j:

```
          (n2) -> (n3)-> (n9)
           /\
           |
   (n4)<-(n1)->(n5)->(n6)
    |            |
    \/           \/ 
    (n7)         (n8)
```

I need two cyphers,
 1- all nodes properties with count of immediate children sorted by count, something like this:

```
node  count
n1      3
n5      2
n2      1
n3      1 
n4      1
n6      0
n7      0
n8      0
n9      0
```

2- All nodes with all their children and grandchildren sorted by count, something like this:

```
  node   count
    n1     8
    n2     2
    n5     2
    n3     1
    n4     1
    n6     0
    n7     0
    n8     0
    n9     0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get only count of childrens back.

```
MATCH (n:Node)
RETURN n,size((n)-[:CHILD]->()) as count order by count desc
```

If you want to get count of children plus grandchildren.

```
MATCH (n:Node)
RETURN n,size((n)-[:CHILD*1..2]->()) as count order by count desc
```

You could also just get back the count of only grandchildren.

```
MATCH (n:Node)
RETURN n,size((n)-[:CHILD*2..2]->()) as count order by count desc
```